# Toggle hide/show on drop down menu select event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a drop down list with id `menuItem`. When a choice is selected I need to display the related list of items via `this.id`.

```
 $("#menuItem").on("click", ".restaurant", function() {
    $(".item").hide().filter("[data-source=" + this.id + "]").show();
    return false;
});
```

Can't get this sub-list to display.

Comment: Please show the relevant html.

Comment: Appreciate it. The function is at the bottom...

http://jsfiddle.net/2h4oLe3r/

Comment: Try `$(this).attr('id')` instead of `this.id`

Comment: If you're going to include a fiddle to demonstrate the problem please make sure it works (other than the specific broken thing you're asking about, obviously). The one you've provided has a drop-down with no items in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working code if anyone was wondering:

```
            $("#restaurant").on("change", function (event) {

                $("option:selected").each(function () {

                   $('.item').hide().filter("[data-source=" + this.id + "]").show();

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in toggling show/hide in the specific element or part of the page then you should use jquery "toggle" function. One simple example for toggles function is given

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("p").toggle();
});
```

This will simply toggle show/hide of "P" element in the page you can specify your elements id.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to toggle all elements of a type, he or she wants to first hide the ones showing, and then show a specific one based on id. So `.toggle()` really isn't going to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(this).attr('id')` instead of `this.id` .... That's proper jQuery syntax...

```
$("#menuItem").on("click", ".restaurant", function() {
        $(".item").hide().filter("[data-source=" + $(this).attr('id') + "]").show();

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: `this.id` is perfectly acceptable. There's no need to do two function calls just to retrieve the same property.

Comment: nnnnnn... correct on both comments. Still trying to resolve the issue. Not sure what I am missing.